# How To Set A PHP GET Variable If It's Not Set

Tags: php

This is what I have.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["var"])) {
echo "1";
} else {
echo "1";
}?>
```

I want it to check if there's been a variable set for "var" and if there isn't (which will happen the first time anyone goes to site), I want it to be set to "1". Then I want to create buttons "back" and "forward" that will will increase "var" by "1" until it reaches my limit of "10" then returns to one.

I can figure out the math and buttons part, I just need help initially setting "var" since it isn't already set when you go to the page.

Comment: why not use SESSION and increment the value instead of manipulating the GET ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, that's why I am asking, so I can learn. @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: the idea is not to temper the super global data, so we have SESSION and which u can use for the very purpose!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from architecture, security and any other issues:

`$_GET` is just a simple array accessible from anywhere in script.

```
$_GET['var'] = 'foo';
```

Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: So you just set it as you would set any kind of variable?

Comment: Yup, but you probably don't want to `$_GET = 1;` as that might screw up other code relying on values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tag

```
<a her="www.example.com?var=<?php echo $get_var?>">your site name</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

the get variables come in to the script like so

```
scriptname.php?getvar=val
```

To "set" the variable you would need to test for it, Increment it and redirect too it

```
$var = 1;
if (isset($_GET['var'])){
    $var = (int) ($_GET['var'] +1);
    if($var > 10) {
       $var =1;
    }
}

header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ."?var=" . $var);
```

as mentioned in the comments, SESSION is a much better place to store this information